# Domain forwarding affects responsiveness of site

Tags: dns, responsive-design, frontend

When you directly visit https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1913634/flading-web-original/index.html on a mobile device – the site acts responsively. Not so, when you visit the site on a mobile device via http://www.cozy-chat.com (and get auto fwd to 2nd domain).

What is going on here?

Comment: unable to access http://www.cozy-chat.com/

Comment: Should work now. I also solved it: I turned off Domain Gripping.